# How to change style of specific characters in Text widget when it is overlapping in a stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart, overlap

I am attempting to dynamically change only specific characters in a Text widget that are overlapped by a loading bar (which is a container).They are all wrapped in a parent Stack widget. However, as the number of characters is subject to change, I am having difficulty implementing this functionality. Are there any suggestions for accomplishing this?

I have attached an example image below of the required design where the loading bar overlap "33" and its colour changes to white but the rest of the number or characters remain gray so if the coloured bar was to overlap the remaining as well then they will change from gray to white too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRugh.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what you're looking for is what would be called "blend mode" in css: https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to implement dynamic resize, there is the package https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

You can set max lines and expected size:

```
AutoSizeText(
  'A really long String',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
  minFontSize: 18,
  maxLines: 4,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```

If you want to restrict the resize feature to a specific set a characters in your `String` you can couple it with a `RichText` widget that allows to separate style and more within a `Text` widget.

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Colin. I actually need to change the colour of the characters in a string that are overlapped by my loading bar. Again the original string is not known, it is dynamic so I cannot set anything beforehand

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to help me understand the requirements please ?

Comment: I have added an image as an example on the post. Can you see the link?

Comment: I apologize I have just made sure that the link is visible now. If you can please take a look. Will be much appreciated